# "Sport", "sports", and "sporting" as modifiers

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Is there a difference between a "sports jacket", a "sport jacket", and a "sporting jacket"? Or are these merely dialectal differences?

For instance, why do various outerwear and sportswear brands call some pieces "sports" and others "sporting" within a same collection or line?

It sounds to me like "sporting" designates only those pieces associated with recreational countryside/outdoor activities like hunting, fishing, and bird watching, and so a "sporting jacket" would be a sort of country-style, multi-pocket, mid-length waxed/waterproof coat with or without a hood.

That said, we say "sporting house" and "sporting lady" as euphemisms for "brothel" and "prostitute", and "sporting goods" has a sense of sportswear items at large to it rather than a specific range.

Unlike "sporting", I guess "sports" and "sport" might have some relation -- to a lesser or greater degree -- with cars, back in the old days when the activity of driving an automobile would imply a certain attire, composing mostly of a jacket, a cap, and a pair of gloves. From these bygone days might have originated the terms "sports" and "sport" found in "sportswear", "sports/sport car", "sports/sport coat or jacket", etc.

Comment: Is there a question here?  You seem to be calling a for discussion, not asking a question.

Comment: @DavidM You bet there is. I'm asking if there's some kind of difference between the terms specified in the OP.

Comment: I have edited to make the question clearer. If you do not agree feel free to roll back.

Comment: @DavidM Sure, no problem.

Comment: I'm not going to play the edit game with you.  The opening line should be is there a difference. Or is it a matter of dialect. The hairbreadth of difference is not particularly descriptive or useful here.

Comment: How's that? I didn't make any change to the opening line.

Comment: I edited it, and you rolled it back to this. Perhaps it was accidental.

Comment: @David M It surely was.

Comment: I actually like this question... I hear them all used more or less interchangeably at times and not at others - perhaps there is some kind of story to it.

Comment: @Nourished No worries then, I've edited it to be a bit more in keeping with the language of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sport/Sports jacket is the same thing.  It is a a suit jacket that is less informal than your normal business suit.  In the midwest US I hear sports used more but when on the east coast I hear sport.  The meaning is the same.

Sporting jacket is something that I have heard but it is not commonly used.  If someone said they had a sporting jacket, the first thing that would come to my mind is hunting.  It would bring up visions of men prancing around on their horses chasing foxes.  Either way I wouldn't use this term in normal speech unless I was trying to convey hunting mixed with either upper-class or in some sort of dated story.

Comment: How about for "sporting store" vs. "sports store", "sports goods vs. "sporting goods", and "sports/sport" sweater vs. "sporting sweater"? Would a sporting sweater not be one with stitched elbow and shoulder patches and a crew neck, generally worn in the military and by hunters, fishermen, and other outdoor enthusiasts?

Comment: On the store naming, as far as the US it depends on where you are from.  It is really by area and sports/sport/sporting all range from selling normal sports equipment (baseball, football, soccer, tennis...) to hunting/fishing stuff.  In my area sporting is used for hunting/fishing but this is not a rule.  For sweater, maybe.  It is just a dated term that was never used much.  If you wrote a story set in the pre-80s and there was hunting involved then yes but I would look for something else.